What kind laptop do I have?
My serial number is xc20662r , it's a Toshiba I know that but I wanna know the year and stuff like if I tried to search for it what would I type in? I can't for the life of me find it anywhere please help me out thanks.

We don’t need your serial number, we can’t use it to identify your make and model, but the label on your device should help with doing that. At the very least provide what region the product is from.

If it boots up into Windows, load System Information. The System Summary panel shows you System Model

